# Define a function as taking any object with given properties

Tags: c#

Consider a function `LengthOfName`; it takes in an object which has a `name` property, and returns the length of it's name:

```cs
class Dog {
  public string Name;
}

class Human {
  public string Name;
}

class MainClass {
  public static int LengthOfNameDog (Dog dog) {
    return dog.Name.Length;
  }

  public static int LengthOfNameHuman (Human human) {
    return human.Name.Length;
  }

  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    var Fido = new Dog { Name = "Fido" };
    var Alex = new Human { Name = "Alex" };

    Console.WriteLine (LengthOfNameDog(Fido));
    Console.WriteLine (LengthOfNameHuman(Alex));
  }
}
```

This isn't great, as we have to repeat ourselves. I understand that there is already a standard way around this, namely to have `Dog` and `Human` inherit from a single class, for instance:

```cs
class ThingWithName {
  public string Name;
}
class Dog : ThingWithName {}
```

Which is fine. **The problem I'm having is that I'm using class definitions which are auto-generated from Entity Framework**, so I don't think I'd want to mess with their class to say they inherit from some master class.

What I'd like to be able to do is to implement a function which takes in an instance of *any* object which has given properties, in the example above, for instance, any object which has the `Name` property.

Is this possible in c#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Entity Framework generates partial entity classes, you can define an interface with a `Name` property and create another partial class for each entity type that implements this interface:

```
public interface IHasName
{
     string Name { get; }
}

public partial class MyEntity : IHasName {}
public partial class MyOtherEntity : IHasName {}

public static int LengthOfNameHuman (IHasName entity) {
    return entity.Name.Length;
}
```

If the entities don't share a common base class or interface, you'll have to use reflection to get the `Name` property.